# Add an image to the background of a button in Xaml

Tags: android, ios, image, xaml, button

I have 4 buttons arranged in a grid. I want each button to display an image exactly the size of that button, but am at a loss as to how to do this. I'm trying the following method right now, but am given the error "cannot set the content of button as it does not have a content property attribute" when I include the  line.

I tried adding an image to the first button in the grid, but the image is far too large. I want the image to perfectly overlay the size of the button, regardless of the size of the phone I'm using.

This is my code:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Welcome," HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Aqua"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="User" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Aqua"/>     
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Image="iris_light" Text="Student&#x0a;Directory" TextColor="Aqua"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="Executive&#x0a;Directory" TextColor="Aqua"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Voting" TextColor="Aqua"/>

        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="Map" TextColor="Aqua">

            <Image Source="iris_light"/>

        </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: A possible solution would be overlaying two grids on top of one another. One grid with the images, and one grid with the buttons. But when I place a grid on top of another, the grid on the bottom is not visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem:

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Welcome," HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Aqua"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="User" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Aqua"/>     
        <Image Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Source="iris_light"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Text="Student&#x0a;Directory" TextColor="Aqua"/>
        <Image Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Source="iris_light"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Text="Executive&#x0a;Directory" TextColor="Aqua"/>
        <Image Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Source="iris_light"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Text="Voting" TextColor="Aqua"/>
        <Image Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Source="iris_light"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Text="Map" TextColor="Aqua"/>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that (meaning that the Image property is not flexible enough for you), you must write a custom renderer.

Unlike Windows, iOS and Android are not based on the XAML so content of their controls is not editable that way as it is not supported by the underlying OS.